# Where does iTunes keep the "trackid" for files which reside on iCloud via match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, audio, metadata, itunes

Goal is to update audio metadata with iTunes store for files which only reside on the iCloud.
I found a handy Ruby script which would perform the task if the file was re-downloaded locally http://cl.ly/C3kK

The script enlightened me to the itunes store api, however, I still need the itunes store trackId which is not to be confused with the local/internal trackId or persistentId. The above script reads in the first MB of the physical audio file looking for a magic number and storing the subsequent integer. I peeked at the itunes music library.xml with no luck. Itunes is storing this information somewhere I would think. Or at least the another ID can be used to retrieve the metadata from the iCloud.
In the end I would simply update the itunes music library.xml with the results from the itunes store api.

I realize there are iCloud iTunes api calls, but before I delve into that subject I would rather post a question to the experts.

Any help on the subject would be amazing.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since you posted this question, but I encountered the same issue you had and was able to figure it out. The iTunes store trackId is stored in the downloaded version of an iTunes matched file. If you grab the first 1024 bytes of data from the file, the track id is the first 4 bytes of data after the string 'song'. You'll need to convert it to a decimal from a signed 32-bit integer.

Example: No Cars Go (Arcade Fire)

```
file_string = File.open(path, 'r').read(1024)
index = file_string.index('song')
@iTunes_id = file_string[index+4,4].unpack('N')[0]
print "Song ID: #{@iTunes_id}"
```

Results in:

```
Song ID: 81607936
```

Now, you can take that ID and look up the track data from iTunes:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=81607936&country=US
```

Results in:

```
{
 "resultCount":1,
 "results": [
{"wrapperType":"track", "kind":"song", "artistId":23203991, "collectionId":81607965, "trackId":81607936, "artistName":"Arcade Fire", "collectionName":"Arcade Fire EP", "trackName":"No Cars Go", "collectionCensoredName":"Arcade Fire EP", "trackCensoredName":"No Cars Go", "artistViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/artist/arcade-fire/id23203991?uo=4", "collectionViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/no-cars-go/id81607965?i=81607936&uo=4", "trackViewUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/no-cars-go/id81607965?i=81607936&uo=4", "previewUrl":"http://a644.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/060/Music2/v4/ba/95/be/ba95be41-4a03-4dea-2965-57dd5f0b66c0/mzaf_6092501386391248238.m4a", "artworkUrl30":"http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Music/y2005/m10/d01/h10/mzi.yfrupnuj.30x30-50.jpg", "artworkUrl60":"http://a2.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Music/y2005/m10/d01/h10/mzi.yfrupnuj.60x60-50.jpg", "artworkUrl100":"http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Music/y2005/m10/d01/h10/mzi.yfrupnuj.100x100-75.jpg", "collectionPrice":6.93, "trackPrice":0.99, "releaseDate":"2005-01-10T08:00:00Z", "collectionExplicitness":"notExplicit", "trackExplicitness":"notExplicit", "discCount":1, "discNumber":1, "trackCount":7, "trackNumber":3, "trackTimeMillis":364071, "country":"USA", "currency":"USD", "primaryGenreName":"Alternative", "radioStationUrl":"https://itunes.apple.com/station/idra.81607936"}]
}
```

I hope this helps the OP or anyone else, I wasn't able to find this information anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since you posted this question, but I encountered the same issue you had and was able to figure it out. The iTunes store trackId is stored in the downloaded version of an iTunes matched file. If you grab the first 1024 bytes of data from the file, the track id is the first 4 bytes of data after the string 'song'. You'll need to convert it to a decimal from a signed 32-bit integer.